# How do I store the results of the for loop as an array in the res variable?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to store the results of the for loop as an array in the variable 
`$res`. How do I do it?

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $name =  "abc";

    $con = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $name);

    $sql1 = $con->query("SELECT (status) FROM `seita`"); 

    $i = $sql1->num_rows;
    echo $i;

    for($x=1; $x<=$i; $x++)
    {
        echo $x;
        $sql = $con->query("SELECT status FROM `seita` WHERE RollNo = '$x'");
        $res = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);
    }
?>
```

The answer given by Rohit Mittal gave me array to string conversion error. What do I do next?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all in one query with `fetch_all()` of mysqli

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$name =  "abc";
$con = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $name);
$result = $con->query("SELECT status FROM `seita`")->fetch_all();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to do it all in one line. Maybe something similar to this:

```
$res = $con->query("SELECT status 
    FROM `seita` 
    WHERE RollNo between 1 and (
        SELECT count(status) 
        FROM `seita`
    ) 
")->fetch_all();
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to make an array and need to get only status value as below:

```
$res = [];
for($x=1; $x<=$i; $x++)
    {
        echo $x;
        $sql = $con->query("SELECT status FROM `seita` WHERE RollNo = '$x'");
        $statusData = mysqli_fetch_row($sql);
        $res[] = $statusData['status'];
    }
```

Comment: Then [edit] your original question and show us the desired output and what you are getting now. Without knowing what you want we can only take a guess. What Rohit provided will create an array with the results from the query as you asked.

Answer (score -2):

You want to append to an array search google `php array append` which gives `array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");`

```
// Declare arrray
$res = []

for($x=1; $x<=$i; $x++)
{
    echo $x;
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT status FROM `seita` WHERE RollNo = '$x'");

    // Append result to array
    array_push($res, mysqli_fetch_row($sql));
}
```